# FLINK left join three DataStreams using cogroup

Tags: java, left-join, apache-flink, flink-streaming, data-stream

I'm trying to merge three stream into a single stream. Tried union but was unable to proceed as the schema's are different and if I merge the schema it becomes too large.

So, I'm using  **cogroup ** to do a left join and return a tuple of three streams.

```
`
DataStream<Tuple3<Schema1, Schema2, Schema3>> mergeJoin = stream1.coGroup(stream2)
        .where(genericRecord -> {return   SchemaUtils.getKey1(genericRecord);})
        .equalTo(genericRecord -> {return   SchemaUtils.getKey2(genericRecord);})
        .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(3)))
        .apply(new LeftOuterJoin1())
        .coGroup(stream3)
        .where(tuple_Schema1_Schema2->{return   SchemaUtils.getKey1(tuple_Schema1_Schema2);})
        .equalTo( genericRecord->{ return SchemaUtils.getKey3(genericRecord);})
        .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(6)))
        .apply(new LeftOuterJoin2());
`
```

```
public static class LeftOuterJoin2 implements CoGroupFunction<Tuple2<schema1, schema2>, GenericRecord, Tuple3<chema1, schema2, schema3>> {

        @Override
        public void coGroup(Iterable<Tuple2<SCHEMA1, SCHEMA2>> iterable, Iterable<GenericRecord> iterable1, Collector<Tuple3<SCHEMA1, SCHEMA2, SCHEMA3>> collector) throws Exception {
            final SCHEMA3 NULL_ELEMENT = null;
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            for (Tuple2<SCHEMA1, SCHEMA2> leftElem : iterable) {
                boolean hadElements = false;
                for (GenericRecord rightElem : iterable1) {
                    SCHEMA1 schema1_data = leftElem.f0;
                    SCHEMA2 schema2_data = leftElem.f1;
                    SCHEMA3 schema3_data = mapper.readValue(rightElem.toString(), SCHEMA3.class);
                    collector.collect(new Tuple3<>(schema1_data, schema2_data,schema3_data));
                    hadElements = true;
                }
                if (!hadElements) {
                    SCHEMA1 schema1_data = leftElem.f0;
                    SCHEMA2 schema2_data = leftElem.f1;
                    collector.collect(new Tuple3<>(schema1_data, schema2_data,NULL_ELEMENT));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
While merging the first two streams of tuple with the third on **apply(new LeftOuterJoin2())** \ i'm getting 
> 
> Cannot resolve method 'apply(LeftOuterJoin2)' error.

Expecting1: A tuple of three streams.
Expecting2: Number of records should be equal to SCHEMA1 count.
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `Either3<Schema1, Schema2, Schema3>` class that's similar to Flink's `Either`. In each of your three incoming streams, you'll convert your records to an `Either3` with the appropriate field set. Then you can key the stream and use a `KeyedProcessFunction` to do whatever you want to do on the data.